# AngularJS translate bool to localized string

Tags: angularjs

I want to translate a bool to something from my localization. Usually I can translate with this expression: `jhiTranslate="keepath.to.my.translated.property"`

So I thought this would work:

```
 <span>{{data.isValid ? jhiTranslate="myApp.data.isValid" : jhiTranslate="myApp.data.isNotValid"}} </span>
```

How can I access the translation function inside my property-binding?

By the way - this one works:

```
<span>{{data.isValid ? 'valid' : 'not valid'}} </span>
```

Comment: Do you use `$translateProvider`?  Does this work: `<span jhiTranslate="keepath.to.my.translated.property"></span>`

Comment: Also what is `jhiTranslate`? any plugin/framework?

Comment: I use the translationProvider from JHipster. It works with dependency injection. So I have to put "true" and "false" in my json translation files?

Comment: what sort of expression is `jhiTranslate="keepath.to.my.translated.property"`

Comment: keepath.to.my.translated.property is just the path inside my json file that I have configured for the translation service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this :

```
<span jhiTranslate="{{ 'keepath.to.my.translated.property' + data.isValid }}"></span>
```

And in jour translation file you put :

keepath.to.my.translated.property.true = YES
(in the language you want)